# How can you use the values you get from the Counter class in python?

Tags: python

for example ...

```
x=[1,1,2,1,5,2,1,3]
```

and then when i 'Counter' it
i get

```
Counter({1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 1, 5: 1})
```

can I reuse the second numbers? So let's say I want to print one out 4 time because I have 4 ones in the Counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can treat the `Counter` object as a dictionary:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x=[1,1,2,1,5,2,1,3]
>>> c = Counter(x)
Counter({1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 1, 5: 1})
>>> number_of_ones = c[1]  # returns 4
>>> number_of_twos = c[2]  # returns 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`Counter` is a child class of `__builtin__.dict`. Therefore you can access its elements by key just like you would with a dictionary.

```
>>> x=[1,1,2,1,5,2,1,3]
>>> c=Counter(x)
>>> c[1]
4
```

Excerpt from the docs:

> class Counter(__builtin__.dict)
>      Dict subclass for counting hashable items.  Sometimes called a bag
>      or multiset.  Elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts
>      are stored as dictionary values.